# Disagreement with an edit

Tags: support

I disagree with an edit on my recent post: [How can a new freelancer judge the competition?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/462/how-can-a-new-entrant-judge-competition)

The edit in question is by Mod: Robert Cartaino.
Revisions: https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/posts/462/revisions

I understand his concerns, but I do not agree with the edit. I have perfectly good reasons to cross-post and promote another question for the widest choice of answers. Is there a guideline that prohibits me from doing so? If not, I wish to roll back the edit please.

I agree that it might be chatty, and I can fix that, but that's all that I believe is wrong with the question.

Comment: The disagreement has sort of been resolved in the comments on that question. Either Robert will post an answer here, or I'll do it later and close this off.

Answer (score 3):

Think of this like fight club:

> The first rule of Stack Exchange is that you don't talk about Stack Exchange

...unless answering and linking to relevant material, or on meta, and so on. It's not *absolute*,  but you should get the general idea.

Generally, anything "meta", about questions, answers, or otherwise goes *on* meta.

The Stack Exchange model is best described as *high signal, low noise*. In other words, if something in a question or answer isn't actually the question or answer, it can (and should) be edited out.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Hiroto on this one.

Rule 1: don't disagree with the mods unless you have a very good reason.

So you have a very good reason? Good. Interesting. Let's have a look.

> I understand his concerns, but I do not agree with the edit. I have perfectly good reasons to cross-post and promote another question for the widest choice of answers. Is there a guideline that prohibits me from doing so?

Cross-posting on several StackExchange sites isn't a good idea. However, as far as I know, this is not the reason for the edit. The reason for the edit was that the last two lines did not contribute to the question as the question. It's some kind of meta-about-the-question-talk. It's best to do that in the comments.

You could have commented with:

> I cross-posted this to achieve [goal] here: [link]

And:

> I couldn't find suitable tags for this question - if you have any, please (suggest an) edit!

What's most important here:

**Robert Cartaino didn't edit your post because cross-posting is wrong, but because the lines he edited out weren't of any use to the question.**

> I agree that it might be chatty, and I can fix that, but that's all that I believe is wrong with the question.

That's good. You can fix it by adding comments, but please do not add this information to the body of the question. That's not what questions are for.

Comment: Camil - Thanks! That's exactly what got discussed in the comments. But funnily, Robert seems to disagree with that info being present in the comments too! And what about the lack of communication for the edit, coming from a Mod?

Comment: @bPratik most of the edits are obvious, he'd have thought that in this case as well. Remember, they have enough to do! In the comments, he says: "That's not the purpose of comments either, but go for it. I'll let the community decide what to do with it (if anything) from here." My experience with several communities is that they don't really care about such comments.

Comment: Camil - Mod or not, a disagreement is exactly that. They are humans too, they are under a lot of pressure and their decisions sometimes need to be taken with a pinch of salt. But that is exactly what they are for, and they opted into it, and theirs is the responsibility to calmly face this disagreement. This is an open forum, not an aristocratic one where hierarchy should have an effect on opinion! :)

Comment: sorry... a comment too late! :)

Comment: @bPratik and that's why he replied to your comments. You cannot expect moderators or whoever to discuss everything until you have a perfect agreement. That's why Robert leaves it to the community to now - and that's how StackExchange works. That isn't aristocratic at all :)

Comment: And, yes I wholeheartedly agree with you, which is why I didn't start a rollback war! I thought I'll leave it to the opinion of others, more experienced than me! But thanks though! :)

Comment: Actually, Robert did mention cross posting in the question is bad. The goal is to get people to visit *this* site, not use it as a platform to promote content on some other site. As far as disagreeing with mods goes, I don't think that's harmful as long as it's done constructively and politely, *which it was*, with the goal of learning how the site works or possibly improving a process. Just remember, the community team is here to help us make this site succeed, and they have plenty of experience empowering communities to win. :)  Hope this helps! :)